# initcap in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to exchage a part of email before @, i.e. 'MARIE.SUE' from 'MARIE.SUE@example.com'. Then i need to make first symbol UPPER - 'Marie.sue'. Initcap makes this: 'Marie.Sue'. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Postgres has a initcap function in the last version https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html search for initcap

Comment: @nbk, It looks to me that's exactly what OP tried and will capitalize more than just the 1st letter of a string.

Answer (score 1):

With `split_part` and `INITCAP`

> ```
> SELECT INITCAP(split_part('MARIE.SUE@example.com','@',1)) ||'@' 
> || split_part('MARIE.SUE@example.com','@',2)
> ```
>
> ```
> | ?column?              |
> | :-------------------- |
> | Marie.Sue@example.com |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT INITCAP(split_part('JOe.DOe@example.com,uk','@',1)) ||'@' 
> || split_part('JOe.DOe@example.com.uk','@',2)
> ```
>
> ```
> | ?column?               |
> | :--------------------- |
> | Joe.Doe@example.com.uk |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e6047da10b200e0d278f70d9be463378)*

Answer (score 0):

With PostgreSQL 9.6 (or above) try to utilize `REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY()` since a positive lookbehind is supported:

```
WITH S AS (SELECT REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY('MARIE.SUE@example.com', '(?<=^.|@)') AS ARR) SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(ARR[1]),LOWER(ARR[2]),ARR[3]) FROM S
```

See an online [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/93640/0).

---

This would:

- Uppercase the first character;
- Lowercase anything else before '@';
- Keep everything intact after '@'.

The pattern `(?<=^.|@)` means to match any position preceded by the start of the string and any character ***or*** by an literal '@'.

---

**Note:** In case you don't want the substring from '@'-onwards, try:

```
WITH S AS (SELECT REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY('MARIE.SUE@example.com', '(?<=^.)|@.*') AS ARR) SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(ARR[1]),LOWER(ARR[2])) FROM S
```

Or, without `REGEX()`:

```
WITH S AS (SELECT LOWER(SPLIT_PART('MARIE.SUE@example.com', '@', 1)) AS X) SELECT UPPER(LEFT(X,1))||SUBSTRING(X,2) FROM S
```

See an online [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/93642/0)